# Subject-control verbs

Tags: verbs, gerunds, infinitives, gerund-vs-infinitive

I have been studying Raising and Controlling, but it seems quite hard to understand its function and uses.
I would like any of you to analyze this explanation and tell me whether I got it correct or not:

**Subject-control verbs** are verbs that take a *to-infinitive phrase* as its complement and its subject is the same who performed the main action, for example:

> **The man** tried [to run faster]

In the sentence above, the subject of the to-infinitive phrase is the same who performed the action of trying (**The man**).

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. _Try_ governs A-Equi ("Equi" is another name for "Control"), where the downstairs subject is controlled by the upstairs subject. B-Equi is where it's controlled by the upstairs indirect object, like _I told him to take out the garbage_. There's also A-Raising and B-Raising, [with similar structures but different verb classes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Comment: P.S. Do you still call it a control verb in "The man tried running faster"?

Comment: @Aml - Yes, for "running faster" is also a non-finite clause.

Comment: Gosh, that explanation you cite has a grammar mistake.  "Subject-control verbs are verbs that take a to-infinitive phrase as ***its*** complement".

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about it is as a subject complement.

The man (Subject) tried (verb) to run (infinitive) faster (Adverb).

The complement refers to the subject.

An example of an object complement would be:

The people chose the candidate who was tallest.

In this case, who was tallest? The object - the candidate.

In the first example, the subject is running.

I don't know if this helps but when I am stumped, I often try to substitute concepts or in some cases pronouns or tenses to test various grammatical problems or to help my comprehension.